# Why does my jQuery click function not do anything?

Tags: jquery, click, live

Here is my HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="taskID-1">
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a>
            </td>
            <td data-field="complete">
                <input type="checkbox" name="tasks" id="checkID-1">
            </td>
            <td data-field="description" colspan="100">
                <label for="checkID-1">Description of task numero uno.</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="taskID-2">
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a>
            </td>
            <td data-field="completed">
                <input type="checkbox" name="tasks" id="checkID-2" value="Description of task number 2" checked="checked">
            </td>
            <td data-field="description" colspan="100">
                <label for="checkID-2" class="line-through">Description of task number 2.</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="add">
            <td colspan="100">
                <a href="#">add task</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="editRow">
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="cancel">cancel</a>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="description">
            </td>
            <td>
                <menu class="saveButtons">
                    <a href="#" class="save close">save</a>
                    <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
                </menu>
            </td>        
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('.add a').live('click', function() {
// hide the .add row and show the .editRow
$(this).closest('table').children('.edit').hide();
$(this).closest('table').children('.add').hide();
$(this).closest('table').children('.editRow').fadeIn();

return false;
});
```

Comment: it should... might want to debug your JS, might be some other issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the only child of `table` is `tbody` and it has neither class `edit` nor `add` or `editRow`. You might want to use `find` instead:

```
$(this).closest('table').find('.edit').hide();
$(this).closest('table').find('.add').hide();
$(this).closest('table').find('.editRow').fadeIn();
```

But as I don't know what you actually want to achieve I cannot say if this is doing what you want ;)

Comment: Of Course! Thanks.  I was about to go crazy.

Comment: @Radek S: This would only work if `a.edit` is an ancestor of the clicked element`. And I think it is not. And then `$(this).closest('a.edit')` would be even better. You cannot combine `closest` and `find`.

Comment: I have multiple a.edits and so only the first answer works with my code.